# Can calibrated lidar and camera data be considered as labeled data?

Tags: machine-learning, camera-calibration, point-clouds, calibration, lidar

I will train my neural network with calibrated lidar and image data. Would this data be considered as labeled data? Can this network be trained with unsupervised learning? Is there any chance this model actually learn correctly from this data? I am open to any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: This question may be better suited to the Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) site which is about machine learning and other statistical analysis. If your questions was more specific to programming you'd have more luck here.

Comment: Here is some material on the subject from Stanford (https://web.stanford.edu/~rqi/pointnet/docs/cvpr17_pointnet_slides.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to model whether or not you can consider it labelled.

What do you consider "labelled". If you are creating a model to predict position in the x/y/z (or rae) coordinate system then lidar is labelled data. If you are trying to model whether something is "up" or "down" then the data is not yet labelled (although that may be an easy to calculate feature).

You also mention photos. A lot of machine learning is used to determine what is in a photo. A lidar scan won't label what the contents of a photo are. So the photo wouldn't be labelled.

For supervised learning you have to have all of the outcomes labelled. If you run a machine learning algorithm and don't specify the outcomes then your data is unlabelled and the algorithm will be unsupervised. Or you can partially label the data for semi-supervised algorithms.

Example 1: You take a set of photos that are labelled "cat" or "dog" and then make an algorithm to determine whether a photo is of a cat or a dog. This is supervised.

Example 2: You take a set of photos that aren't labelled but you've looked at them and they are all either night scenes or day scenes. You don't label the data and feed it into an algorithm to find 2 clusters. The algorithm splits the photos very well because the photos in each group are very distinct without any labeling. This is unsupervised.